# bash chmod number condition

Tags: macos, bash

I found how to output the numeric chmod value of a file from the following question.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46915/get-the-chmod-numerical-value-for-a-file

How would I check if this number is greater than a certain value in a condition?

Note:

```
host:path user$ stat -f "%OLp" file
644
```

---

```
# !/bin/bash

file=/path/file

if [ stat -f "%OLp" $file -gt 644 ]; then
    echo Greater than 644
else
    echo Less than 644
fi
```

---

```
Syntax error: ./bash.sh: line x: [: too many arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
stat -f "%OLp" $file
```

is a command you need to execute and compare the result with `644`.

So we should be using [command substitutions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to run the command in a subshell.

```
if [ $(stat -f "%OLp" $file) -gt 644 ]; then
```

- The `$( )` runs the command and replaces it with the output of the command.

**Test**

```
$ if [ $(stat -f "%OLp" $file) -gt 644 ]; then
>     echo Greater than 644;
> else
>     echo Less than 644; 
> fi
Less than 644
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, have an answer and rep.

Comment: Accepted answer. However, this is a new account. Looks like I can't upvote until I get 15 rep :)